# Implementations Basics (Costs, Timescales, etc)

Tags: database, migration

We're looking for indicative figures with regards to migrating across an Access Database to CiviCRM. Early stages (but we need to migrate soon as our Access config is grinding to a halt) so any ideas of the likely costs, timescales, other resource requirements, etc would be very much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Greg

Comment: Hi Greg - not sure how substantive an answer you will get for this type of question on SE. 'length of string' is likely to bandied about. Generally, for doing this kind of work, we would go through an analysis of the complexity of the Access db, confirm the outcomes you require from civi, and assess how much of the civi config is work that you or other members of your team can undertake. Ping me via skype peter.davis59 or pd at fuzion.co.nz if you would like to discuss this further to help you figure out some of this answer - or contact others at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

Comment: From a Civi Documentation stand point, this is a good place to start: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/getting-prepared/is-civicrm-for-you/

Answer (score 6):

Honestly without a significant amount of detail regarding your current database, how you're going to use CiviCRM, what kind of site it is being connected to, etc, no one can give you anything but a huge range - I've seen it done for as cheap as $3,000 and as high as $30,000.

Some things to consider:

How clean is your data? Is there going to be a significant amount of data cleaning needing to be done by the person who works on your Civi install? I've done some where folks did not follow any sort of best practices with their data and you had state abbreviations mixed with state names, email addresses in phone fields, etc.

What is your list of fields needed? If a field is something other than a textfield, what are the options? Is it a single choice or multiple choice? Is it required?

What are you going to use CiviCRM for? What are you going to be doing with it? Membership? Donations? Paid events? Free event? Etc. You need a good list of how you as an organization plan to interact with Civi.

How is the public going to interact with it? What actions will they be able to take?

What kind of site is it going to be attached to (Drupal, Wordpress, etc)? Is it built already or will the developer need to do that as well?

Look - do you have an idea how you want your public facing Civi pages to look?

Your timescale is really going to depend on what all needs to be done, how responsive you guys can be regarding feedback, and the like.

Resources - obviously your database. There would need to be a development area to work on that isn't your live site. Most developers have their own if you don't have one available. That will allow the site to be worked on and developed, but blocked from view from the public. I've only ever used a Linux server for Civi setups. And they can quickly use up a lot of space because of the size of the database as well as a good amount of memory. As such, regular shared hosting is not recommended. There are hosts, though, who have configured a dedicated server specifically for Civi and then divide it into "shared" hosting. That gives you more resources than the typical shared hosting account.

Hopefully this at least gives you some idea of what to consider and look for. Please let me know if you have any questions. :)